# undefined method `edit_comment_path' (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Post model and a Comment model (which is a nested resource of the first model):

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

**posts/show.html.erb:**

```
<%= render @comments %>
```

I think I have some error in here:

**comments/_comment.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Edit Post Comment", [@post, edit_comment_path(comment)] %>
```

because I get this error:

```
undefined method `edit_comment_path' for #<#<Class:0xb439d8c>:0xaeaf4c0>
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: `rake routes` will give you the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run `rake routes` you can see the route names, in your case the route name should be `edit_post_comment_path` rather than just `edit_comment_path`.

Comment: I tried `[@post, edit_post_comment_path(comment)]` but now I'm  getting this: `undefined method `post_/posts/4/comments/2/edit_path' for #<#<Class:0xb008fb0>:0xb006b70>`. This is what I found in my routes: ` edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)`

Comment: Pass both the parameters to the path: `link_to "Edit Post Comment", edit_post_comment_path(@post, comment)`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `<%= link_to "Edit Post Comment", [@post, :edit, comment] %>` or `<%= link_to "Edit Post Comment", edit_post_comment_path(@post, comment) %>` (untested, can't test here).

Because `edit_comment_path` is, like rails says, undefined.